# AWS EC2 Free tier data transfer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Does changing **t2 micro free tier** to **unlimited** cause also unlimited out internet data transfer?

Answer (score 0):

Data transfer is unrelated to t2 unlimited. T2/T3 unlimited lets your T series EC2 instance use as much CPU as it needs, rather than the limited amounts found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t3/) - e.g. 5% for t3.nano.

If you turn T2 unlimited on and your CPU usage is above the included limit you will pay for the extra usage. You will always pay for bandwidth above the amount included with the [free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/).

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I read and completely understood burstable. just had confusion about data transfer! but one more question remain that why aws services have such high bandwidth price 0.09 per gigabyte while there is also some reliable unlimited provider like ionos and also some good reputation ones with more than 1 terabyte on under 10 usd per month service with same cpu ram !!!

Comment: I expect bandwidth prices are high because Jeff Beazos needs another space rocket

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Tim's answer:

The T family of EC2 instances are based on a burstable vCPU utilization policy. Each size has it's own baseline vCPU utilization. t3.nano can use up to 5% 24x7 for free and can "burst" up to 100% vCPU utilization for short periods of time without extra cost. Credits are generated for time spent below the baseline and spent for each minute of "bursting".

Unlimited mode allows for longer bursting times and doesn't charge more if the 24-hour average utilization is at or below the baseline. In relation to your question, Unlimited mode does not affect data transfer. It only affects vCPU utilization and burstability for the instance.

from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances-unlimited-mode.html

> If you use a t2.micro or t3.micro instance under the AWS Free Tier
> offer and use it in unlimited mode, charges might apply if your
> average utilization over a rolling 24-hour period exceeds the baseline
> utilization of the instance.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I read and completely understood burstable. just had confusion about data transfer! but one more question remain that why aws services have such high bandwidth price 0.09 per gigabyte while there is also some reliable unlimited provider like ionos and also some good reputation ones with more than 1 terabyte on under 10 usd per month service with same cpu ram !!!